# How to manage api rate limiting in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, httprequest, rx-java, http-status-code-429

My server accepts 60 requests per minute (per IP) and if it is more, it will return 429 error code (Too Many Requests).
In my Android app I have a bottom navigation and in each fragment I call several requests to get updated data from the server.
How can I manage the rate limiting error and have the new data?

I detected 429 error code and forcing the user to wait a minute to call a new request. But it has a very bad UX.

Comment: There's probably not much you can do with there being a hard limit on allowed requests per minute, besides just asking your users to "try again later".

Comment: Caching may help for rarely updated data (if you have such) data. For frequent updates you can also look at webscocket (used by chats etc)